# background: fixed; disappearing on scroll in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

When scrolling down the page in Chrome, my fixed background elements flicker and completely disappear at one point in the page. I coded this in Chrome, and it only just became an issue, so I'm not sure what's up.

I've tried changing the position to static, webkit clipping, z-index, positioning the background, changing it from repeat, everything I could possibly find. I can't seem get a fixed image to work inside of the div to do that roundabout fix, so I was wondering if there's a way I can keep the image in the CSS.

```css
#neverlosethatenergy {
  width: 85%;
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/lw6rtk6.jpg) fixed repeat;
  font: 24pt 'facile';
  color: #ffbed2;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: right;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#neverlosethatenergy .silence {
  background-color: rgba(17, 14, 6, .75);
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 7px;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <div id="neverlosethatenergy">
    <font class="silence">TITLE</font>
  </div>
</center>
```

You can find the issue [here](http://shadelings.life/?showforum=1). The issue is only in Chrome. Everything seems to work completely fine in other browsers.

Comment: Your HTML code contains deprecated tags. Please consider to rewrite your HTML first.

Comment: It doesn't look like your image is "flickering" and disappearing, that looks like a parallax scroll to me

Answer (score 0):

The scrolling effect seems to go away simply by removing "fixed repeat" as such:

background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJPK5.jpg);

Try this?

Comment: Hi! I'm actually hoping to keep the scrolling effect. The issue I'm having is that, as I scroll down the page in Chrome, the background disappears once I reach a certain point on the page.